# user added by(who added this user)

Tags: users

I want to know who added every user in all users menu in the back-end, I used 'get_the_author' but it must be within the 'loop' which cann't be in all users menu that the condnition willnot be verified, Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a plugin called WP Security Audit for tracking all things any additional users on sites im building are doing on the backend. You can set the plugin to only show to certain user roles as well. Link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/ If you're only trying to see this information on the backend that may help

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple enough in concept - get name/ID of logged-in user at time the action is performed with get_currentuserinfo(): https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo. Would be easier to answer more specifically if you explained precisely where and how you wanted the information to turn up and what code you're looking at now where you're trying to use get_the_author

Comment: I'm trying to get check first if there are users then the problem is echoing the user name who make the action of adding the user, here is my code `$args = array();$user = new WP_User_Query($args);if ( $user->have_posts() ) : while ( $user->have_posts() ) : $user->the_post(); 
$current_user = get_the_author();
$var = $current_user->user_login; return $var;endwhile; else :
_e( 'Sorry, no users matched your criteria.' );
endif;`

Comment: I'm still unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve, but I THINK you want to get and display information that first has to be added to the WP user database (user_meta). I THINK you're trying to call data programmatically that doesn't exist and won't exist until you create it. So, when an admin-level user (identified via get_currentuserinfo() or variant) added a new user, that admin-level user (or his/her user ID) would be automatically added to the new user's meta_data as a NEW "added_by" field. After, when the new user's information appears, you can also retrieve the "added_by" user meta.